# Resize windows/controls ratio in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to be able to resize the ratio of a windows forms along with each of its controls/text/etc. So the goal is to allow the user to select the size depending of the resolution of the screen.

How can this be achieved?

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using methods and properties such as

- [`Control.Scale(SizeF)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158413.aspx)
- [`ContainerControl.AutoScaleFactor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalefactor.aspx)
- [`ContainerControl.AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx)

and others.

You can do this in several ways. One way would be to scale entire form using [`Control.Scale(SizeF)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158413.aspx) method.

```
this.Scale(new SizeF(2, 2));
```

This will scale entire form and it's child controls by factor of 2 by width and height. However, font sizes will not be scaled.

Another way would be to set `AutoScaleMode` to `Font` and change font size of the form. Form and controls will scale accordingly.

```
AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
Font = new Font("Helvetica", 20);
```

You should read more about this [in MSDN article called Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx).

Comment: how can I get this 'new SizeF(2, 2)' according to screen resolution like if I want to scale according to resolution, my application is fixed at 1024*600 so if I am trying at 1366*768 than how can I calculate the SizeF to apply, screen resolution can vary.